# Monitoring php command line worker with Monit Ubuntu 20

Tags: php, monit, ubuntu-20.04

Problems monitoring php script using pid method.

We have a Laravel worker script that must be kept running on the server:

`php /data/git/site/directory/artisan queue:work --daemon` when this is run on the command line it holds the terminal open and does not output anything until the Laravel app pushes output to it - this is unlikely to be within 30 seconds of start up.

I wrote a bash script as suggested (/usr/local/bin/artisanqueue):

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
    start)
       echo $$ > /var/run/artisanqueue.pid;
       exec 2>&1 php /data/git/site/directory/artisan queue:work --daemon 1>/tmp/artisanqueue.out
       ;;
     stop)
       kill `cat /var/run/artisanqueue.pid` ;;
     *)
       echo "usage: artisanqueue {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Then we created /etc/monit/conf.d/laravel, and have tried two versions, first 'matching'

```
# artisanqueue
check process artisanqueue
    matching "artisan queue:work"
    start program = "/usr/local/bin/artisanqueue start"
    stop = "/usr/local/bin/artisanqueue stop"
    if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Second 'with pidfile' as suggested https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/FAQ#pidfile

```
# artisanqueue
check process artisanqueue with pidfile /var/run/artisanqueue.pid
    start program = "/usr/local/bin/artisanqueue start"
    stop = "/usr/local/bin/artisanqueue stop"
    if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

In the monit.log

```
[UTC Oct 11 23:02:04] debug    : 'artisanqueue' process test failed [pid=93896] -- No such process
[UTC Oct 11 23:02:04] error    : 'artisanqueue' process is not running
[UTC Oct 11 23:02:04] info     : 'artisanqueue' trying to restart
[UTC Oct 11 23:02:04] debug    : 'artisanqueue' process test failed [pid=93896] -- No such process
[UTC Oct 11 23:02:04] debug    : 'artisanqueue' process test failed [pid=93896] -- No such process
[UTC Oct 11 23:02:04] info     : 'artisanqueue' start: '/usr/local/bin/artisanqueue start'
[UTC Oct 11 23:02:34] error    : 'artisanqueue' failed to start (exit status -1) -- Program '/usr/local/bin/artisanqueue start' timed out after 30 s
[UTC Oct 11 23:03:06] info     : 'artisanqueue' monitor on user request
[UTC Oct 11 23:03:06] info     : 'artisanqueue' monitor action done
[UTC Oct 11 23:03:08] debug    : 'artisanqueue' process test failed [pid=93987] -- No such process
[UTC Oct 11 23:03:08] error    : 'artisanqueue' process is not running
[UTC Oct 11 23:03:08] info     : 'artisanqueue' trying to restart
[UTC Oct 11 23:03:08] debug    : 'artisanqueue' process test failed [pid=93987] -- No such process
[UTC Oct 11 23:03:08] debug    : 'artisanqueue' process test failed [pid=93987] -- No such process
[UTC Oct 11 23:03:08] info     : 'artisanqueue' start: '/usr/local/bin/artisanqueue start'
[UTC Oct 11 23:03:38] error    : 'artisanqueue' failed to start (exit status -1) -- Program '/usr/local/bin/artisanqueue start' timed out after 30 s
```

Simultaneously looking at processes we see it running but with a different PID number

```
ubuntu@dev-us:/data/git/site/directory$ ps faux | grep 'artisan queue'
ubuntu     94064  0.0  0.0   7704   652 pts/0    S+   23:03   0:00              \_ grep --color=auto artisan queue
root       94039  0.9  2.6 124340 50484 ?        Ss   23:03   0:00  \_ php /data/git/site/directory/artisan queue:work --daemon
```

We can confirm that Monit is looking at the same PID number as is present in `/var/run/artisanqueue.pid` but it changes somewhere in that process, I'm assuming when the restart happens, but I can't confirm where.

```
[UTC Oct 11 23:23:06] error    : 'artisanqueue' failed to start (exit status -1) -- Program '/usr/local/bin/artisanqueue start' timed out after 30 s
```

How do I get a consistent result here?

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and Monit version 5.26.0

Comment: I don not know how artisan work, but you can use an addition timeout for the start command, see https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-METHODS.

But in general the command used to start an application should end after the appliaction is up an running.
If the application switch to a new process, it seems to me, you should use matching to find/monitor the process in the check process statement.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried extending the timeout too, but no luck yet. When I run `php /data/git/site/directory/artisan queue:work` on the command line it only runs while the terminal is open.

Comment: Hmm, as long as you can not start artisan in a background process, you can not start artisan with Monit. Try something like "/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/php /path/to/artisan queue:work --daemon etc &" on the command line.